# Como puedo llamar informacion de Firebase Database a Android Studio y mostrarla en un activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

Buen dia,
Tengo esta informacion guardada en Firebase Database
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera leerla y mostrarla en un activity de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo esto de codigo, nose cual seria la opciona mas sencilla o como se usaria el metodo onDateChange
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

primero tienes que agregar tu proyecto a firebase, luego importar las librerias correspondientes en este caso seria las librerías de FireBaseDatabase, ahora si vamos al Codigo, Lo puedes hacer de dos maneras

```
fReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   //si hay cambios realizados
    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    // Failed to read value
    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
}});
```

tambien puedes hacerlo con el evento ChildListener

```
ChildEventListener listener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

          String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);//si se agrego un nuevo hijo los valores de ese hijo estaran en la variable String value
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
```

y en tu Oncreate

```
fReference.addChildEventListener(listener);
```

la funcion add te muestra todos los que se van agregando en tiempo real, la funcion changed te muestra enseguida los cambios realizados en tiempo real la de move si se movio el archivo o los datos la de removed pues si fueron eliminados

Espero haberte ayudado ;) saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Ricardo, muy amable

Comment: dale, para eso estamos

Comment: con eso me sallen organizados es que me aparece en pantalla al ejecutar -LNGazUhOVVUC8lcKVTO: "Hipoglucemia:50 Fecha:25/9/2018 Hora:11:42" todo esto sin orden ni filas

Comment: ah en ese caso utiliza un modelo, ya que como tu mostraste, pues todo eso lo has mostrado en linea, por lo que te saldrá en linea,  te pongo un ejemplo, al momento de guardar tienes el modelo hipoglucemia ahi pones hipoglusemia.setfecha("fecha"); etc etc.. y cuando vayas agregar pues agregas fReference.setvalue(hipoglucemia); y cuando vayas a recibir recibes por el modelo  seria algo como hipoglusemia value=dataSnapshot.getvalue(hipoglusemia.class); y luego revibes el archivo en una variable como ejemplo emm String fecha = value.getfecha();jajaja por comentarios se complica xD espero ayudarte

Comment: ah cuando me refiero en linea fue que lo  has guardado en una sola varible que la llamaste hipoglusemia, y pues veo que tienes docis pues si son las docis para tratar la hipoglucemia deberia ponerla en el mismo hijo por ejemplo el hijo enfermeda tie hipoglucemia tiene la fecha en la que le dio, pues supongo y tiene el tratamiento, ahora como te comente antes para agregar  es mejor a través de modelos y recibes a través del mismo modelo

Comment: Muchas gracias lo probare como entendi y te respondo con imagenes de los implementado